# Does wp_login only trigger before an user signs in into the admin panel?

Tags: plugin-development, login

Saw this bit of code in a plugin:

```
public function wp_login($user_login, $user) {
    Identify::create($user->ID);
}
```

Fires after the user has successfully logged in.

In the doc it says that it fires when the user has successfully logged in, so does that mean that the user signed in to log into the admin panel, or can wp_login be used to do something else? It's confusing, because there's a plugin that declares its own wp_login function.

```
$this->add($this->actions, 'wp_login',  $frontend, 'wp_login', 10, 2);
```

I am thinking the defined wp_login is a callback to the other wp_login which is confusing, and it creates an user upon the user signing in into the admin panel.

Comment: [wp_login](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2900d9eccf46ede0b3bec4d56906c7a199b38eb7/wp-includes/user.php#L110) fires after the user has logged in. If you're ever in doubt look at the source :)

Comment: There isn't really a difference between logging into the admin panel and not logging into the admin panel, the same user sessions are created regardless of the redirect destination. Also I do not understand your reference to creating the user, users are created on registration, not login, otherwise login would fail because no such user exists.